# how to add next previous buttons to popup using js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I tried to add the next button on the popup box. Now it is run popups in a specific order. Also, when the final popup open, the button disable automatically. but there is an issue. when I delete some modal, the code is not working. I want to run popups in that order and when I delete some popup, the popups want to run correctly. Also, I want to create the previous button. how can I do it? please help me to fix the issue.

Here is the code I used.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
       var currentmodal = 1;
       $(".getAssignment").click(function() {
          var $divs = $(".modalDialog");
          var modal = $("*[data-modalorder="+(currentmodal++)+"]");
          if(!$("*[data-modalorder="+currentmodal+"]").length)
          {
              modal.find("input.getAssignment").prop("disabled",true);
          }
          if ($divs.length > 0 && modal) {
              window.location.href = "#" + $(modal).attr("id");
          }
       });
    });


    <input class="getAssignment" type="button" value="Open Modal">

    <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog" data-modalorder=1>
        <div>
        <input class="getAssignment" type="button" value="Previous">
        <input class="getAssignment" type="button" value="Next">
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
       <h2>Modal Box 1</h2>
            <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
            <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="openModal2" class="modalDialog" data-modalorder=2>
        <div>   
       <input class="getAssignment" type="button" value="Previous">
       <input class="getAssignment" type="button" value="Next">
       <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
       <h2>Modal Box 2</h2>
            <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
            <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Sanjeewani/q1tm8ck2/10/

Answer (score 0):

The condition which you are using in js returns always true and length of the array is not boolean so you do require it to compare it with an integer. Sample below:

```
$("*[data-modalorder="+currentmodal+"]").length==0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".getAssignment2").click(function() {
   var pNode = $(this).closest(".modalDialog");
   if(pNode.prev(".modalDialog")){
     var id = pNode.prev(".modalDialog").attr("id");
     window.location.href = "#" + id;
   }
 });
 $(".getAssignment").click(function() {
  var pNode = $(this).closest(".modalDialog");
  if(pNode.next(".modalDialog")){
    var id = pNode.next(".modalDialog").attr("id");
    window.location.href = "#" + id;
  }
 });
});
```